# Is there any way to check if there is a table that has field names that I want in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

1. I have about 200 words to be used as field names.
2. If a table that has those words as field names is found, I do not have to create a new table.
3. But if a talbe that has those words as field names is not found, I have to create a new table.

Please help me to find the way to check if a table that has those words as field names exists.

I found here codes below

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME 
IN ('lNum','rNum', 'tTime') AND TABLE_SCHEMA='summary';
```

But this codes didn't help me because it matchs one of them in list.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by " didn't help me because it matchs one of them in list"? Isn't it what you want?

Comment: it feels like a bad idea... i geuss your are looking for a query where a table matches **all** fields in the `IN()` ...  You need to add `GROUP BY TABLE_NAME HAVING SUM(COLUMN_NAME = 'lNum') AND SUM(COLUMN_NAME = 'rNum') AND SUM(COLUMN_NAME = 'tTime') > 1`.. Then you also can remove the DISTINCT keyword..

Comment: Also, maybe that's an XY problem, maybe we could help better if you explain why you want to do this..

Comment: _Columns_, not fields.

Comment: @Kaddath: I receive summarys which are results for tests of semiconductors from subcontractors. They have about 200 parameters each. But sometimes the parameters are added or removed by necessity a little bit for the same product. So if the summarys I get do no match column name of a table, I need to create a new table. The code I mentioned above didn't match all of the column names in IN list at the same time. It matched one of them, which are not the one that I wanted.

Comment: Your query works fine with InnoDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not a direct answer for your question, but it was too long for a comment.

Usually this kind of problem is solved by having separate tables, one that references the properties you want to save, and another that saves the values. This way, you can dynamically add and remove properties to the list. Having 200 of them could lead to huge tables, of course, but you can still separate them into different tables that can be referenced in a third table.

An example:

Table that references properties (id corresponds to the type in second table):

```
----------------------------
| id | name  | description |
----------------------------
| 0  | prop0 | bla         |
| 1  | prop1 | blabla      |
| 2  | prop2 | blablabla   |
----------------------------
```

Table that store values:

```
---------------------------------------------------
| id | type | test | value                        |
---------------------------------------------------
| 0  | 1    | 0    | one prop1 val for test 0     |
| 1  | 2    | 0    | one prop2 val for test 0     |
| 2  | 2    | 1    | another prop2 val for test 1 |
---------------------------------------------------
```

Another example that separate sets in different tables

Table that references other tables:

```
-----------------------------------------------
| id | name   | propertiesTable | description |
-----------------------------------------------
| 0  | table0 | prop0           | bla         |
| 1  | table1 | prop1           | blabla      |
| 2  | table2 | prop2           | blablabla   |
-----------------------------------------------
```

Tables correponding to the first row:

```
prop0:                          table0
----------------------------    ---------------------------------
| id | name  | description |    | id | type | value             |
----------------------------    ---------------------------------
| 0  | prop0 | bla         |    | 0  | 1    | one prop1 val     |
| 1  | prop1 | blabla      |    | 1  | 2    | one prop2 val     |
| 2  | prop2 | blablabla   |    | 2  | 2    | another prop2 val |
----------------------------    ---------------------------------
```

Of course, if you have a lot of code already written with tables that are not referenced, you can go with Raymond Nijland's comment solution, but that will lead to huge requests by adding 200 conditions.

Another solution that is between the 2 is to reference all your tables in another table like in my second example, with a field that stores a concatenation in alphabetical order of all your columns, something like `column1;column2;column3`. This way you can test in one short request if there is a table that have exactly all your fields with a comparison.

Other combinations with this concept are possible that can suit better to your purpose, you can adapt it if you understand the general method.

Good luck!

Comment: I don't know what to ask because I have no idea of the concept about what you said. I think about it for two days but I have no ideas of it. Could you please tell me about it different way if possible?

Comment: ok, wondering why you accepted the answer then ^^ the general idea is to use a table to keep track of the possible properties (the columns in your static tables) for your different types of tests. This way you can add properties / search them more easily. If you want to keep separate tables for the tests, you can use another table to list your tables and their columns. There are lots of possibilities depending on the flexibility you want.

Comment: There was a progress for understanding what you said. In the first two tables you showed as an example, What is description for? What is test column?